# Allocando memoria mediante una funcion en mi lista enlazada

Tags: c, lista

luego de romperme la cabeza implementando mi lista enlazada simple unidireccional
queria saber porque mi funcion `appendNode()` no funciona
que estoy haciendo mal?

```c
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct Node {
    char* data;
    struct Node* next;
};

// inserta un nodo nuevo al final de la lista
void appendNode(struct Node* root, char* data)
{
    // creamos el nodo allocandole memoria
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    // asignamos valores al nodo nuevo
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;

    // en caso la lista no tenga elementos
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = temp;
        return;
    }

    // creamos un iterador apuntando al comienzo de la lista
    struct Node* it = root;

    // recorremos hasta el final de la lista de nodos
    for (; it != NULL; it = it->next);

    // enlazamos con la lista
    it->next = temp;
}

// recorre los nodos hasta el final e imprime contenidos
void printNodes(struct Node* root)
{
    // navegamos los nodos con un iterador
    for (struct Node* it = root; it != NULL; it = it->next)
    {
        printf("%s\t", it->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// TODO: Liberar la memoria al finalizar el programa
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;

    appendNode(head, "Alberto");
    appendNode(head, "Raul");
    appendNode(head, "Francisco");

    printNodes(head);

    exit(0);
}
```

cuando uso el debugger MSVC me indica que `head` siempre es `NULL` entonces la condicion de asignar la cabeza nunca termina de cumplirse y no se como solucionar eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### El problema

El problema es que en C no tienes la sintaxis para especificar que un parámetro va por referencia, cosa que necesitas si vas a cambiar el valor del parámetro desde dentro de la función.

Para empezar por algo simple, imagina que tienes una función que recibe un parámetro y quieres que la función lo ponga a cero, de modo que el programa principal pueda hacer:

```
int n = 100;
poner_a_cero(n);
```

y a la vuelta te encuentres que `n` vale cero. Bueno, no es posible hacer tal cosa en C (no con la sintaxis mostrada). En C++ en cambio harías esto:

```
void poner_a_cero(int &x)  // &n indica que el paso es por referencia
{
  x = 0;
}
```

y ya estaría, pero C no admite un `&` como parte de una declaración, y si no ponemos `&` tendríamos lo siguiente, que obviamente no va a funcionar:

```
void poner_a_cero(int x)   // NO VA A FUNCIONAR como queremos
{
  x = 0;
}
```

Aunque esto no tiene errores de sintaxis, el cero que guarda en `x` no tendrá efecto sobre la variable `n` que el programa le está pasando como parámetro, pues `x` no es más que una copia local que existe sólo dentro de la función.

**Exactamente este es el problema que estás teniendo** en tu código, pues cuando dentro de él asignas `root = temp` estás en realidad cambiando el valor de la variable local `root` de esa función, sin modificar el de la variable que había sido pasada como parámetro.

### ¿Cómo lograrlo entonces?

En C (y en C++ también, ya puestos) puedes usar punteros para simular el paso por referencia. El truco es que el programa principal, en lugar de pasar a la función una variable `n`, lo que le pasa es *la dirección* donde esa variable está almacenada. Es decir, el programa principal sería así:

```
int n = 100;
poner_a_cero(&n);
```

Al pasar la dirección de `n`, la función recibe una dirección en la que puede escribir otra cosa (el cero!) y por tanto modificar directamente una variable externa. La función ahora ya no recibe un `int` sino un **puntero** a `int`, que se declara con un `*`. Para acceder a la dirección a la que apunta ese puntero debe usar un `*` delante de la variable. La función quedará ahora así:

```
void poner_a_cero(int *x)
{
   *x = 0;
}
```

La sintaxis `*x=0` mete un cero en la dirección a la que `x` apunta. Y ya que `x` contiene `&n` (la dirección de `n`) meterá allí un `0` y `n` cambiará de valor como queríamos.

### En tu caso

En tu caso la cosa se complica un poco más, porque la variable del programa principal que quieres cambiar es `head` que se declara así:

```
struct Node* head = NULL;
```

Para que una función pueda modificar su parámetro debes pasarle la dirección de una variable, como vimos antes en el ejemplo `poner_a_cero()`. Usando la misma idea aquí, habrá que pasar la dirección de `head` a las funciones que deberían modificarla. Por ejemplo:

```
    appendNode(&head, "Alberto");
```

El problema es que ahora lo que estamos pasando con `&head` es *la dirección de un puntero*, es decir, un **puntero a puntero**. Eso por tanto obliga a reescribir la función `appendNode()` para que su primer parámetro sea de tipo puntero a puntero a Node (que se declara poniendo **dos asteriscos**). Así:

```
void appendNode(struct Node** root, char* data)
```

y obviamente en el interior de la función, en todas partes donde dijera `root` ahora debe decir `*root`, pues `root` es un puntero que apunta a `&head`, por lo que usar `*root` será acceder a `head`.

Comment: muchas gracias no sabia que tenia que ponerle ampersand como parametro del `appendNode()` ya pude solucionarlo

Answer (score 1):

La variable `head` solo es asignada una vez, a `NULL` en la primera línea de la función `main`.

Intuyo que con las siguientes líneas buscas asignar la variable `head` del main:

```
if (root == NULL) {
    root = temp;
    return;
}
```

`root` es un parámetro que recibe una copia del valor de `head`. No son lo mismo.

Para lograr tu cometido, la función debe recibir la posición en memoria de `head`. Necesitas un puntero a puntero.

O sea, el parámetro `root` debe ser de tipo `struct Node**`.

Dentro de la función solo tendrías que modificar estás líneas:

```
if (*root == NULL) {
    *root = temp;
    return;
}

struct Node* it = *root;
```

Y la función `main` debería ser así:

```
struct Node* head = NULL;

appendNode(&head, "Alberto");
appendNode(&head, "Raul");
appendNode(&head, "Francisco");
```

Otra cosa. Piensa detenidamente este código:

```
for (; it != NULL; it = it->next);

it->next = temp;
```

Si el for se detiene cuando `it` es `NULL`, la asignación de abajo daría error ya que estás intentando definir una posición de memoria inválida.

Lo que necesitas verificar es que `it->next != NULL` así `it` nunca será `NULL`.

Comment: Hola Mateo, gracias por responder; a pesar de que tengas razon y la sintaxis esta correcta. Ahora me sale otro error donde dice que estoy violando el acceso de lectura. Es que la verdad estoy muy confundido, yo entiendo que tengo que utilizar por referencia el parametro de la funcion pero no se como hacerlo con punteros. Los ejemplos que hay en internet son extremadamente simples y no hay casos donde expliquen como usar punteros para referenciar. Las vueltas que le doy a mi cabeza explican que al final el puntero por parametro si apunta a la direccion de memoria, lo que no se es porque no deja

Comment: Yo no estoy haciendo un arreglo de nodos para iterarlos despues.. solo es un nodo conectado al siguiente. Me frustra un poco no entender que suceden con los parametros, un puntero es una variable que guarda una posicion de memoria, cuando usas * te refieres al contenido de este, y cuando solo escribes su nombre es la mismisima direccion a la que apunta verdad? entonces usar * o & en los parametros deberia ser lo mismo. Y otra cosa que no se es que devuelve exactamente malloc. Te agradeceria si pudieras probar el codigo que pusiste para que me detalles cosas

Comment: * es el operador de indirección. Lo que hace es leer el valor en la posición de memoria a la que apunta. En el caso de tener una expresión como `*root = temp;` significa que quieres cambiar el valor de dicha posición de memoria. En C no se puede pasar por referencia como sí lo harías en C++ con `&`. Lo que sí puedes pasar son valores o direcciones de memoria.

Comment: ah no lo sabia yo vengo de C++ queriendo hacer C por eso me la paso mal